# Why do member names hide type-dependent name lookup?

Tags: c++, name-lookup

If I have a free function:

```
 enum BOM { utf8, utf16le };
 size_t length(BOM b);
```

And then I have a class with a member named length:

```
 struct foo {
     BOM m_bom;
     size_t length() { return length(m_bom); }
  };
```

Why does the use of length(m_bom) fail to find the free function using type dependent lookup?

I'm using VS2015, but I suspect that they've got these rules right by now, so the question is probably a language question...

Comment: Did you try using namespaces?

Comment: The member function shadows, rather than overloads, the free function. Once the member function is found, the lookup is over, even if the arguments don't match.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is kind of ironic, since you've obviously seen it - you left a comment there. But don't feel bad, I've done the same thing myself.

Comment: lol - not only have I seen it b4, but I still agree with myself: this behavior sucks and is a wrong choice for the language.

Comment: You were misled by yourself :) It isn't a wrong choice.

Comment: Yes, it is.  type-binding lookup is far more consistent and this is a flaw in c++ - fundamentally so.  Unless you can link me to a set of arguments / examples that show how it would be a worse language the other way round.